# Formatting "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" timestamp to Date

Tags: r, date-formatting

I have a data set with two columns, house prices and the date (and time) of sale, although the time is 00:00 for all of them. The date column has the format of YYYY-MM-DD 00:00.

I want to remove the time from the column so that the column is left with just the date which I can then sort in an order and plot on a graph.

Comment: use `as.Date( x )` (assuming your current data is POSIXct-format)

Comment: See https://www.r-bloggers.com/date-formats-in-r/ for the different possible date formatting options for `as.Date()`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is in the format you specified you can simply use `as.Date()` like so:

```
b = '2018-09-20 12:30'

a = as.Date(b)
```

[Try it out](http://rextester.com/PTZV72598)